# R: converting comma separated entry to columns with non-characters

Tags: r

I have a column of names in R that are separated by a comma.

For example:

```
    John, Doe
    Rebecca, Homes
```

I'd like to separate the first and last names into separate columns.

One additional problem I have is that sometimes there will be a name that doesn't have a comma.  For example:

```
    John, Doe
    Rebecca, Homes
    Organization LLC
```

I've looked at using strsplit(a, ","), but I get the following error Error in strsplit(wn, ",") : non-character argument.

Here is an example within Stack [Convert comma separated entry to columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8464312/r-converting-comma-separated-entry-to-columns)

Any help regarding solving this simple problem will be greatly appreciated.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In 2 steps :

1. You can use `read.table` with `fill=TRUE`, to read all lines (You can also use readLines)
2. treat without commas as seprator.

The code is something like this :

```
aa <- read.table(text='John, Doe
Rebecca, Homes
Organization LLC',sep=',',fill=TRUE,colClasses='character')

## treat lines without comma
aa[nchar(aa$V2) ==0,] <- 
      do.call(rbind,strsplit(aa[nchar(aa$V2) ==0,]$V1,' ')) ## space as separator :I assume you 
                                                               don't have compound  name

> aa
            V1     V2
1         John    Doe
2      Rebecca  Homes
3 Organization    LLC
```

**EDIT**  better method : I use a reglar expression to replace any space by a comma to have regular separator. I assume that you don't have any compound name.

```
ff <- readLines(textConnection('John, Doe
Rebecca, Homes
Organization LLC'))
do.call(rbind,
strsplit(gsub('[ ]|, |,[ ]',',',ff),','))
```

Comment: if I want to include the column name instead of text='John, Doe Rebecca, Homes'.  What should I used instead of text = ?