# Read data stored as character

Tags: r, summarization

I have a column within a dataframe with numbers that looks like this below

```
      City                Temperature
      Edmonton, Alberta   4.1,13.6,15.2,15.7,14.2,15.2,16,14.2,17,13.1
      Edmonton, Alberta   15,18.2,14.8,16.5,14.6,16.9,14.3,17.5,13,15.8
      Edmonton, Alberta   15.8,17.9,16.9,15.1,13.2,13.1,16.8,12.4,14.7,15.6
      Edmonton, Alberta   14.3,17.3,14.6,17.3,14.8,14,15.4,14.1,16,15.4
```

My objective is to read the data in `Temperature` column and create two additional columns that stores the Minimum and Maximum temperatures like this.

```
      City                Temperature                                         Min      Max
      Edmonton, Alberta   4.1,13.6,15.2,15.7,14.2,15.2,16,14.2,17,13.1        4.1      16
      Edmonton, Alberta   15,18.2,14.8,16.5,14.6,16.9,14.3,17.5,13,15.8       13       18.2
      Edmonton, Alberta   15.8,17.9,16.9,15.1,13.2,13.1,16.8,12.4,14.7,15.6   12.4     17.9
      Edmonton, Alberta   14.3,17.3,14.6,17.3,14.8,14,15.4,14.1,16,15.4       14.1     17.3
```

I tried the simple `min(df$Temperature[1])` function but it didnt work. So not sure how to deal with this data, any advise or suggestion is much appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert comma separated entry to columns](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8464312).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `scan` function can read across text fields and parse out values divided by the "sep" argument:

```
> dat$min_temp <- sapply( as.character(dat$Temperature), 
                    function(x) min( as.numeric( scan( text=x, sep=",", what=""))))
Read 10 items
Read 10 items
Read 10 items
Read 10 items
> dat
              City                                       Temperature
1 Edmonton,Alberta      4.1,13.6,15.2,15.7,14.2,15.2,16,14.2,17,13.1
2 Edmonton,Alberta     15,18.2,14.8,16.5,14.6,16.9,14.3,17.5,13,15.8
3 Edmonton,Alberta 15.8,17.9,16.9,15.1,13.2,13.1,16.8,12.4,14.7,15.6
4 Edmonton,Alberta     14.3,17.3,14.6,17.3,14.8,14,15.4,14.1,16,15.4
  min_temp
1      4.1
2     13.0
3     12.4
4     14.0
```

Comment: Ah the scan function,  I knew that for some reason I couldn't connect. Thanks 42,

Answer (score 3):

We need to `split` the 'Temperature' column by ',', convert to `numeric`, get the `range`, `rbind` it and create two columns

```
df1[c("Min", "Max")] <- do.call(rbind, lapply(strsplit(as.character(df1$Temperature), ','), 
                        function(x) range(as.numeric(x))))
```

The `as.character` is only needed if the column 'Temperature' is `factor` class.

Comment: this worked but I am going with the scan function suggested by 42 above just because i can add other summary statistics easily using scan function if needed, for example I am not sure how to include average if needed in the future using this approach, but I relate well with scan function.

Comment: @DiggyDetroit For the average, you can do `function(x) {x1 <- as.numeric(x); c(range(x), mean(x))}))` also change the `df1[c("Min", "Max", "Mean")] <- `