# How to split a a long-string in a column in different string columns in R?

Tags: r, string, split

If my first column of a matrix is a long string, how can I split it in different string columns? or instance:

```
     V1    V2   V3

a-b-c-d  1000  100

e-f-g-h  1100  110
```

and obtain:

```
     V1    V2   V3   V4   V5   V6

      a     b    c    d  1000  100

      e     f    g    h  1100  110
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8464312/convert-comma-separated-entry-to-columns or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4350440/split-a-column-of-a-data-frame-to-multiple-columns or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18641951/splitting-a-dataframe-string-column-into-multiple-different-columns or ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# Your sample data
df <-  cbind.data.frame(
    V1 = c("a-b-c-d", "e-f-g-h"),
    V2 = c(1000, 1100),
    V3 = c(100, 110), stringsAsFactors = FALSE);
```

## There ...

```
# Split and cbind new and old columns
df <- cbind.data.frame(
    do.call(rbind.data.frame, strsplit(df[, 1], "-")),
    df[, -1])
colnames(df) <- paste("V", seq(1:ncol(df)), sep = "");

df;
#  V1 V2 V3 V4   V5  V6
#1  a  b  c  d 1000 100
#2  e  f  g  h 1100 110
```

## ... and back again

```
# Concatenate columns 1-4
df <- cbind.data.frame(
    V1 = apply(df[, 1:4], 1, paste, collapse = "-"),
    df[, -(1:4)]);
colnames(df) <- paste("V", seq(1:ncol(df)), sep = "");    
df;
#       V1   V2  V3
#1 a-b-c-d 1000 100
#2 e-f-g-h 1100 110
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.. do you know how to make the inverse process? from the V1, V2, V3 and V4 to just one V1 with a-b-c-d?

Comment: @FelipeRincón I've updated my answer, please take a look.

Comment: PS. If this answers your question, please accept the answer to close the question.

Comment: Not sure why this was downvoted. I posted my answer *before* this was flagged as a duplicate.

Comment: I voted it as good. Thank you very much!

Comment: I voted it as good. Thank you very much!

Comment: Mr Maurits Evers, could you give me an advise about how to solve this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48835464/how-to-manage-a-table-to-obtain-information-using-conditions