# return output as columns instead of list after applying a function using dplyr

Tags: r, list, function, dplyr

```
library(dplyr)
```

Sample data

```
  df <- data.frame(year = rep(1981:1982, each = 365), doy = rep(1:365, times = 2),
                   tmean = sample(20:35, 730, replace = T), ref.doy = rep(c(60, 80), each = 365))

  thermal.df <- data.frame(stage1 = 60, stage2 = 90, stage3 = 120)
```

I have a function

```
  my.function <- function(tmean.ref, doy.ref, thermal.df){

    tm <- tmean.ref[1:length(tmean.ref) >= doy.ref]
    tbase <- 10; topt <- 31;tcri <- 40

    fT <- ifelse(tm >= tbase & tm <= topt,(tm - tbase)/(topt - tbase), ifelse(topt <= tm & tm <= tcri,(tcri - tm)/(tcri - topt), 0))
    thermal.units <- tbase + fT*(topt - tbase)

    stage1 <- as.numeric(thermal.df[, "stage1"])
    stage2 <- as.numeric(thermal.df[, "stage2"])
    stage3 <- as.numeric(thermal.df[, "stage3"])

    pheno <- list(stage1, stage2, stage3)
    return(pheno)
  }
```

Applying function to `df`

```
  df %>% dplyr::group_by(year) %>% 
  dplyr::summarise(x = paste(my.function(tmean.ref = tmean, 
                                         doy.ref = unique(ref.doy), 
                                         thermal.df = thermal.df),collapse = ","))
```

This returns my outputs in a singe column

```
  # A tibble: 2 x 2
      year x        
    <int> <chr>    
  1  1981 60,90,120
  2  1982 60,90,120
```

whereas I want my output as:

```
   year  stage1 stage2 stage3
   1981   60     90     120
   1982   60     90     120
```

Comment: Ideal way would be to re-evaluate your function and write it differently, but a quick and dirty fix would be to add `...%>% separate(x, into = c(paste0('stage', seq(3))), sep = ',')`

Comment: you basically want to [split the comma separated value into different columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8464312/convert-comma-separated-entry-to-columns) ?

Comment: @Sotos That is good but the issue is the number of stages in the function might change. So I need something that splits the x depending on number of elements it has after the functions has run i.e. I do not know a priori the number that should go in `seq(3)`

Comment: The link provided by Ronak has many ways to do that - my personal favourite is [the splitstackshape one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26825460/5635580). Although you only define 3 stages in your function (or is that just an example for demonstration)

Comment: Just modify the code used to wrap your function call :

     `df %>% dplyr::group_by(year) %>% 
       dplyr::summarise(x = list(my.function(tmean.ref = tmean, 
                                             doy.ref = unique(ref.doy), 
                                             thermal.df = thermal.df))) %>%
       unnest %>% unnest %>%
       group_by(year) %>%  mutate(k=paste0("k",row_number())) %>%
       spread(k,x)`

Comment: @Sotos three stages are just for the example